# siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number" when using math in \numrange

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

I want to show a range from 0 to infinity. I'm using this line of LaTeX with `siunitx` imported:

```
\numrange[range-phrase = --]{0}{\infty}
```

That line gives this error:

> siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"

I've also tried with $'s around the `\infty`. What is the correct way to render this range?

Comment: Try placing `parse-numbers=false` in the options for `\numrange`

Comment: Nailed it! Should I delete the question, or should you submit that as an answer?

Comment: Haha, you can go ahead and answer your own question, that's fine with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Troy notes, `\numrange` has a Boolean flag that controls this behavior: `parse-numbers`.

```
\numrange[range-phrase = --, parse-numbers=false]{0}{\infty}
```